# Writing an Euclidean division

Tags: division, euclidean

I want to write this division, but my code doesn't work

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{division}
\author{othnielnzue23 }
\date{October 2023}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} 
\renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{2pt} 
  \begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr} 
 x&-\dfrac{1}{6}x^3&+\dfrac{1}{120}x^5&   &1  &-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 &+\dfrac{1}{24}x^4&  \\ 
\cline{5-7} 
-(x&-\dfrac{x^3}{2}&+\dfrac{x^5}{24}) &   &  &x&+\dfrac{1}{3}x^3&+\dfrac{2}{15}x^5\\ 
\cline{1-2} 
    &2x^2 &   &  &   &   &  \\ 
    &-2x^2&+2x&  &   &   &  \\ 
    \cline{2-3} 
    &     &2x &  &   &   &  \\ 
    &     &-2x&+2&   &   &  \\ 
              \cline{3-4} 
    &     &   &+1&   &   &  \\ 
  \end{array} 
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful description of your problem. Show the exact error message copied from the log, in a code block so line endings are preserved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best code friend

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{division}
\author{othnielnzue23 }
\date{October 2023}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation*} 
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} 
        \renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{2pt} 
        \begin{array}{rrrr|rrrr} 
            x&-\dfrac{1}{6}x^3&+\dfrac{1}{120}x^5&   &1  &-\dfrac{1}{2}x^2 &+\dfrac{1}{24}x^4&  \\[0.5em] 
            \cline{5-7} 
            - \Bigl(x \Bigl. &-\dfrac{x^3}{2}& \Bigl. +\dfrac{x^5}{24}\Bigr) &   &  x&+\dfrac{1}{3}x^3&+\dfrac{2}{15}x^5 &\\ 
            \cline{1-4} 
            &2x^2 &   &  &   &   &  \\ 
            &-2x^2&+2x&  &   &   &  \\ 
            \cline{2-4} 
            &     &2x &  &   &   &  \\ 
            &     &-2x&+2&   &   &  \\ 
            \cline{3-4} 
            &     &   &+1&   &   &  \\ 
        \end{array} 
    \end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

and now it is OK

[image: FINALSCREEN]

Comment: It is the same thing

Doesn't work

Comment: I have the same thing here bu, as you can see, the subtraction lines are not well arranged as in the initial image

Comment: OK, i understand now, wait a minute!

Comment: please, check now!

Comment: Great !!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice array, I had never thought about that arrangement.